# Non-abstract types redundancy in Signature/Functor pattern

Tags: module, ocaml, dry, signature, redundancy

With the Signature/Functor pattern, I refer to the style of `Map.S` / `Map.Make` in the OCaml standard library. This pattern is highly successful when you want to parameterize a large piece of code over some type without making it fully polymorphic. Basically, you introduce a parameterized module by providing a signature (usually called `S`) and a constructor (`Make`).

However, when you take a closer look, there is a lot of redundancy in the declaration:

- First, both the signature and the functor have to be announced in the .mli file
- Second, the signature has to be repeated completely in the .ml file (is there actually any legal way to differ from the .mli file here?)
- Finally, the functor itself has to repeat all definitions again to actually implement the module type

Summa summarum, I get 3 definition sites for non-abstract types (e.g. when I want to allow pattern matching). This is completely ridiculous, and thus I assume there is some way around. So my question is two-fold:

1. Is there a way to repeat a module type from an .mli file in an .ml file, without having to write it manually? E.g. something like ppx_import for module signatures?
2. Is there a way to include a module type in a module inside an .ml file? E.g. when the module type has only one abstract type definition, define that type and just copy the non-abstract ones?

Answer (score 1):

- You can already use ppx_import for module signatures. You can even use it in a .ml to query the corresponding .mli.
- If a module is composed only of module signatures, you can define the .mli alone, without any .ml. This way you can define a module, let's say `Foo_sigs`, containing the signature and use it everywhere else.

Comment: i recently tried the second option and failed to make it build with ocamlbuild. could you post a minimal working example that builds with ocamlbuild?

Comment: Could you provide an example for the first option? How do I ppx_import a signature from the .mli?

Comment: for the first option, camlspotter answered.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating type and module type definitions can be avoided to move them to external `.ml` file. Let's see the following example:

```
module M : sig

  (* m.mli *)    
  module type S = sig 
    type t 
    val x : t 
  end

  module type Result = sig
    type t
    val xs : t list
  end

  module Make(A : S) : Result with type t = A.t

end = struct

  (* m.ml *)
  module type S = sig 
    type t 
    val x : t 
  end

  module type Result = sig
    type t
    val xs : t list
  end

  module Make(A : S) = struct
    type t = A.t
    let xs = [A.x;A.x]
  end

end
```

Instead of writing two files `m.mli` and `m.ml`, I used a module `M` with an explicit signature: this is equivalent to have the two files and you can try it on OCaml toplevel by copy-and-paste.

In `M`, things are duped in `sig .. end` and `struct .. end`. This is cumbersome if module types become bigger.

You can share these dupes by moving them to another `.ml` file. For example, like the following `n_intf.ml`:

```
module N_intf = struct

  (* n_intf.ml *)    
  module type S = sig 
    type t 
    val x : t 
  end

  module type Result = sig
    type t
    val xs : t list
  end

end

module N : sig

  (* n.mli *)
  open N_intf
  module Make(A : S) : Result with type t = A.t

end = struct

  (* n.ml *)
  open N_intf

  module Make(A : S) = struct
    type t = A.t
    let xs = [A.x;A.x]
  end

end
```

You can also use `*_intf.mli` instead of `*_intf.ml`, but I recommend using `*_intf.ml`, since:

- Module packing does not take `mli` only modules into account therefore you have to copy `*_intf.cmi` at installation.
- Code generation from type definitions such as ppx_deriving needs things defined in `.ml`. In this example, it is no the case since there is no type definition.

Answer (score 0):

In that specific case, you can just skip the .mli part:

- Your abstraction is specified by the .ml
- Reading it makes it quite clear (as people know the pattern from the stdlib)
- Everything that you'd put in the .mli is already in the .ml

If you work in a group that's requiring you to actually give a mli, just generate it automatically by using the `ocamlc -i` trick.

```
ocamlc -i m.ml >m.mli # automatically generate mli from ml
```

I know it doesn't exactly answer your question, but hey, it solves your problem.

I know that always putting a mli is considered to be best practice, but it's not mandatory, and that may be for some very good reasons.

As for your second question, I'm not sure I understood it well but I think this answers it:

```
module type ToCopy = sig type t val f : t -> unit end
module type Copy1 = sig include ToCopy with type t = int end
module type Copy2 = ToCopy with type t = int;;
```

Comment: let's say i have other values in the same .ml whose signature i want to constrain. i can't just put those in an .mli and omit the signature of the module M in question in the .mli, since that would hide M to the outside, correct? so in that case, the solution does not seem ideal?

Comment: Correct, you can separate it in two distinct files though (or get the part of the mli you want automatically through a `-i` dump). I agree that some redundancy avoiding would be useful but it can in most times be dealt with through simple workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to camlspoter's answer and since the question mentions pattern matching, maybe you want to "re-export" the signatures and types with constructors declared in `N_intf` so they are accessible through `N` instead. In that case, you can replace the `open`'s with `include` and `module type of`, i.e.:

```
module N_intf = struct

  type t = One | Two

  (* n_intf.ml *)    
  module type S = sig 
    type t 
    val x : t 
  end

  module type Result = sig
    type t
    val xs : t list
  end

end

module N : sig

  (* n.mli *)
  include module type of N_intf

  module Make(A : S) : Result with type t = A.t

end = struct

  (* n.ml *)
  include N_intf

  module Make(A : S) = struct
    type t = A.t
    let xs = [A.x;A.x]
  end

end
```

Then you'll get the following signatures:

```
module N_intf : 
  sig 
    type t = One | Two 
    module type S = sig type t val x : t end 
    module type Result = sig type t val xs : t list end
  end

module N : 
  sig         
    type t = One | Two
    module type S = sig type t val x : t end
    module type Result = sig type t val xs : t list end
    module Make : functor (A : S) -> sig type t = A.t val xs : t list end
  end
```

Now the constructors `One` and `Two` can be qualified by `N` instead of `N_intf`, so you can ignore `N_intf` in the rest of the program.